# Images were taken off Google Patent search

Tags: google-patents, patent-figures

In reference to the patent: [US20140338666](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140338666)

How come the images were taken off Google patents? Is this a bad sign?

Comment: I was about to ask a similar question. I noticed that many of the PDF links are broken as well.

Comment: I asked a similar question a while back, as wondered if you could file a DMCA take down notice against a patent (application). After a question appeared here asking what to do about a filled application that included another's copyrighted material.

Comment: Google has launched a new patent search site since: https://patents.google.com/patent/US20140338666A1/en

Answer (score 1):

Google [just released](http://googlepublicpolicy.blogspot.com/2015/07/good-patents-support-innovation-while.html) an updated interface for their patent search. This is not the only patent currently affected by the glitch, so it is probably safe to assume it will be corrected in the coming days. It won't hurt to use the Send Feedback link at the bottom of their [Patent Search page](https://patents.google.com/) to increase their awareness of the problem.

In the meantime, the images are still available in the PDF and on several other sites, including the USPTO.

Comment: In cases where the patent images and PDFs are both broken on Google, I've been going directly to the Espacenet site to download the full documents there. It has been over a week now since many of the links started failing on Google, so I've been using Espacenet almost exclusively. It is slower but more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

The link to PDFs of patents for patents issued around August 2015 and later remains broken. Try using ImmediateIP.com which has links to PDFs at the US Patent and Trademark Office.

Comment: Hey there, welcome to Ask Patents. Rather than sending users to a third-party website to find links to the USPTO, it might be helpful to give steps to find those links directly *on* the USPTO. At the very least, I'd appreciate if you could give steps to find those links on this site, rather than just the domain name.

Comment: Actually, that website links to Google, Espacenet and WIPO (in case the patent id does not begin with "US") so it is much more useful than USPTO alone.